# Upload Video Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

How to upload video on twitter via tweepy?

I tried with this syntax but it's not working:

```
file = sys.argv[2]
argfle = sys.argv[1]
fn = os.path.abspath('/var/www/html/Gambar/2.mp4')
API.update_with_media(fn, argfile)
```

Output:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Invalid file type for image: video/mp4
```

Answer (score -1):

This following line [from a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106363/tweet-mp4-files-with-tweepy) should help you.

```
upload_result = api.media_upload('/home/user/video.mp4')
api.update_status(status="test tweet", media_ids=[upload_result.media_id_string])
```