# Tweet mp4 files with tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, twitter, tweepy

Hey I'd like to tweet a mp4 file generated using ffmpeg to twitter.
However it seems that there's no real native way to do this with the official tweepy.
When tried with the `api.update_with_media(filename, message)` method, you'll get an error, unsupported file 'video/mp4'

So first I saw a discussion where this github project was linked: [Github link](https://github.com/twitterdev/large-video-upload-python/)

But after testing out the code, the app crashs after the first INIT phase.

So next I saw this: [Github pull request thread](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/929)

And on that thread it was announced that there is a code to tweet video but it hasn't officialy been merged yet, and braian87b made a fork of tweepy with the code to upload videos.

However I have no idea how to install and use a fork of tweepy and how to actually use the code to tweet a video. Braian87b used this as an example code:

```
upload_result = api.media_upload('/home/user/video.mp4')
api.update_status(status="test tweet", media_ids=[upload_result.media_id_string])
```

Any help would be apreciated! :)

Comment: Video upload is not yet implemented with tweepy : https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+upload . And "update_with_media" is deprecated. Sorry but I suggest to use another library.

Comment: Yeah no, I know that. But in the links I provided their was a pull request where a fork of tweepy with the added code to upload video files was advertised. But I had no idea how to actually install and use that fork of tweepy. But in the end I managed to make it work and it can upload video files (almost) flawlessly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I managed to understand it. Making a fork of my own (as the one braian87b provided was incompatible with the latest version of pip, which is what I used to install it), I was able to install the forked tweepy by using pip

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Spyder-exe/tweepy.git
```

and then the code that braian87b provided was in the end perectly good!
So using this code

```
upload_result = api.media_upload('/home/user/video.mp4')
api.update_status(status="test tweet", media_ids=[upload_result.media_id_string])
```

And making sure to put the reply_to_status_id tag **before** the media_ids tag, I was able to upload videos to twitter with only minor annoyances.

Comment: your fork doesnt exist

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but if you want to keep using the official tweepy, you can use the imgur API to upload your media, and then tweet the link (this is what I ended up doing)
`update_with_media` has been deprecated for a long time and once you set up the authentication with the imgur API it's really easy.

Answer (score 0):

we are sending MP4 with less duration but getting media processing status is failed. so what is the format?
ANS
Twitter currently supports the following video formats: MOV and MP4 formats for mobile apps. The minimum Twitter video length is 0.5 second and the maximum Twitter video length is 2 minutes 20 seconds (140 seconds) Twitter supports the following web video formats: MP4 video uploads with H264 format and AAC audio

Use mobile record video you will get your answer